# Can you define an ad hoc anonymous struct in the return type of a function?

Tags: c++, structured-bindings, anonymous-struct

Considering it is possible to create anonymous structs like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} my_anonymous_struct = { 2,3 };

int main() {
    std::cout << my_anonymous_struct.a << std::endl;
}
```

What causes errors to arise in this case?

```
#include <iostream>

struct file {
    int min;
    int max;
};

auto read_historic_file_dates(file F) -> struct { int min; int max; } {
    return { F.min, F.max };
}

int main() {
    file F = { 1, 4 };
    auto [min_date, max_date] = read_historic_file_dates(F);
}
```

Errors:

```
<source>:8:42: error: declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
auto read_historic_file_dates(file F) -> struct { int min; int max; } {
                                         ^
<source>:15:2: error: expected a type
}
 ^
<source>:15:2: error: expected function body after function declarator
```

Is this not possible in C++ (yet)? It would be more declarative than having to use `std::pair`, especially for structured bindings.

Comment: If you use a non-trailing return type, GCC explicitly says that new classes/structs can't be defined in a return type. Unsure about "more declarative", but it would be annoying to have to do `decltype` each time to refer to this struct.

Comment: You could do it with the help of a lambda:https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q7bjjcWh5. However, I am not sure about the GCC error, if that again comes under the case of `decltype(-class definition-)`!!

Comment: @JeJo Yes, but then you still need to define it inside the lambda - and the declarative property will be sort of "hidden" inside there.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I agree. I would rather therefore go with the actual type. i.e. `std::pair, std::tuple, etc`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You don't need to decltype if it's intended to be used with structured bindings.

Comment: What if the user needs to store it as a class member, or pass it to a function?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Then yes, he'd be punished with ugly decltype code.

Comment: A point about terminology: the question is about a **unnamed** struct; there's no such thing as an anonymous struct (except in Microsoft-land). The reason this matters is that there **is** an anonymous union: after `union { int a; long b; };` `a` and `b` occupy the same memory and you can refer to them directly by their names, without having to create an object and use its name to refer to its contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot declare the (anonymous) struct in the declaration of the function:

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

- [[dcl.fct] p17](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#17)

But you can do it in the scope of the function, and use `auto` deduction:

```
auto read_historic_file_dates(file F) {
    struct { int min; int max; } res{ F.min, F.max };
    return res;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting workaround, but it makes it less obvious instead of more what is going on :/

Comment: @glades • that's part-and-parcel standard C++ behavior.  It's not an esoteric dusty corner of C++.  Should be obvious to any C++ programmer what is going on.  (That being said, I prefer the `tuple` approach for an anonymous struct, since that's what a tuple represents.)

Comment: @Eljay I believe the issue is that the return type is spelled out in the function body/function definition vs. the header.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible. You can't declare a function to return an anonymous `struct` since you can't define the `struct` in the function declaration.

So, you need to name this new `struct` or use an existing name, like `file` that seems to fit in your case:

```cpp
auto read_historic_file_dates(file F) -> file {
    return { F.min, F.max };
}
```